# Matlab: concatenate all cells to one matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

The correct words are not coming to my mouth as yet so please tell what I should have asked to make the question clear.

I have a cell array (1x12) with each cell having the size (65536x1). I want to have a matrix which has the dimensions (65536x12). In short, I want to convert (1x12) cell, with each cell having (65536x1) values, to a matrix with (65536x12) values.

[image: cell]

example

[image]

I want to do above programmatically using Matlab but couldn't find any solution. (probably because I am not searching using correct words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**`cell2mat`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

```
output = cell2mat(inputImagesCell)
```

---

You also misunderstood what a "cell array" is, edited your question, maybe it is clearer now. A cell array is an array of cells. `inputImagesCell` is a cell array containing 12 cells, consisting of a 65536x1 numeric matrix each. And you want to concatenate all cells to one matrix.

Comment: @RohanKandwal thanks! You also misunderstood what a "cell array" is, edited your question and made an explanation in my answer